# IOS: search a name in a tableview

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios, uitableview, uisearchbar

I have a tableview with 4 rows and in every row there is a name and a description:
I make a stupid example:

1 - Apple red
2 - Three green
3 - Home big
4 - Table large

inside this tableview I insert a search bar and when I write inside this search bar I want to show only words that I begin to write.

example:
if in the search bar I write "a" I want to see in tableview only "apple red" or
if in the search bar I write "t" I want to see in tableview only "three green" and "table large".
How can I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at the TableSearch sample code project. It should show you everything you need:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableSearch/Introduction/Intro.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007848